# Help me on NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to do sorting for NSMutableDictionary values based on no of players?

Also i want to know how can i append static content with diffrent value like below

```
myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[myDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"no_of_players"];
[myDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"difficulty_level"];
[myDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:120]] forKey:@"duration_excercise"];
[myDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"Excercise_id"];
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: hi..i want to add another set of values in it..i ma not sure how to do..any helps pls

Comment: Are you sing instances of `NSMutableDictionary` as domain objects? In this case you should seriously consider creating a proper domain class. So that you do not have to convert to and from `NSNumber` instances, and you can also implement a custom `compare:` method for that domain object that you can use for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for sorting, your array contains nsmutabledictionaries then you can sort by this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"no_of_players" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    [yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:arrr];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have answered the part of question where you append static content in the question itself.
Regarding sorting check the link below:

[Sort an NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary)

Comment: @pravin: hi..i want to add another set of values in it..i ma not sure how to do..any helps pls

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` are unsorted by nature. The order of the objects as retrieved by `allKeys` and `allValues` will always be undetermined. Even if you reverse engineer the order it may still change in the next system update.

There is however more powerful alternatives to `allKeys` that are used to retrieve the keys in a defined and predictable order:

- `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` -
  Useful for sorting in ascending order
  according to the `compare:` method of
  the value objects.
- `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` -
  New in iOS 4, use a block to do the
  sort inline.