# sort NSMutableDictionary contain object from Json with date string

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having one mutable-dictionary with date key and name key Date key have date in three manner one- expired date,two- upcoming date and nil `(0000-00-00 YYYY-MM-DD)`.
now I wants to sort this `NSDictionary` array in order .
Upcoming date (ascending order).
Expired Date.
Other may be nil I used comparator and sort array in 2 format one array without null value and one is with value and append these array but problem with its not showing with array value in ascending order expired show first...

```
  NSMutableDictionary *JsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
 // NSLog(@"jsondata :%@",JsonDict);

NSArray *arrayData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[JsonDict objectForKey:@"Product"]];

NSMutableArray* filtered =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray*unfiltered =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray*unfiltered1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[arrayData count]; i++)
{

    NSMutableDictionary *reviewsDict123=[arrayData objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([[reviewsDict123 objectForKey:@"date"]isEqualToString:@"0000-00-00"])
    {

        [filtered addObject:reviewsDict123];

    }

    else
    {

        [unfiltered addObject:reviewsDict123];


    }

}
```

unfiltered array have value mixing of present date in 2013 year and 2014 so 2013 value are expired and 2014 value are available so i need to sort 2014 value ascending order and expired will be in another array .

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptors = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
sortedArray = [unfiltered sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

sorted contain expired first now i want to sort again this and how

Comment: NSDictionary is a cocoa container that is not sortable.

Comment: i have json object in nsmutable dictionary and just transfer in nsarray please check edited question

Comment: @Desdenova , while this is true, there are ways to sort the values of the dictionary by copying its values to an array or something like that.

Comment: convert to array then sort

Comment: @user2638242 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary you'd have to go with something like the top answer of that question.

Comment: @Hless right.. but now its affecting my name key if i sort individual array can we sort total key value in nsarray?

Comment: You could copy all dictionary values to an array in the first place, eg: `[{name: "Ex1", date: "date"}, {name: "Ex2", date: "date"}]` and then sort that array by subkey date.

Comment: i tried and now i am able to get sorted value but problem is i getting  expired value first then remain but i need without expired date value even ascending :YES is also not showing ascending result

Answer (score 0):

Correction I have implemented Your case with following way

Create One Test Methods that give me input (In your case Json Response Dictionary)

```
- (void)testDataForApplicationis{

NSMutableDictionary *testDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *testArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[testDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"id"];
[testDict setObject:@"Abcd" forKey:@"name_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"adfasdfasdfadsf" forKey:@"description_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"2014-01-19 00:00:00" forKey:@"start_date"];
[testDict setObject:@"2014-01-19 00:00:00" forKey:@"end_date"];
[testArray addObject:testDict];

testDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[testDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"id"];
[testDict setObject:@"Abcd" forKey:@"name_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"adfasdfasdfadsf" forKey:@"description_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"2014-01-20 00:00:00" forKey:@"start_date"];
[testDict setObject:@"2014-01-25 00:00:00" forKey:@"end_date"];
[testArray addObject:testDict];


testDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[testDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"id"];
[testDict setObject:@"Abcd" forKey:@"name_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"adfasdfasdfadsf" forKey:@"description_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"2013-12-20 00:00:00" forKey:@"start_date"];
[testDict setObject:@"2013-12-01 00:00:00" forKey:@"end_date"];
[testArray addObject:testDict];

testDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[testDict setObject:@"4" forKey:@"id"];
[testDict setObject:@"Abcd" forKey:@"name_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"adfasdfasdfadsf" forKey:@"description_en"];
[testDict setObject:@"2013-08-01 00:00:00" forKey:@"start_date"];
[testDict setObject:@"2013-08-25 00:00:00" forKey:@"end_date"];
[testArray addObject:testDict];
NSMutableArray *promotionModlArray=[PromotionModel getPromotionModelObject:testArray];
 NSMutableArray *sortArray=[self sortPromotionListWithEndDate:promotionModlArray];
}
```

Model Class for map Dictionary in Object and bind date and othere detail with one Object

Here Class name is ***PromotionModel*** here in .h file

```
@interface PromotionModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *promotionid;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *promotionName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *promotionDesc;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *promotionStartDate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *promotionEndDate;

+ (NSMutableArray*)getPromotionModelObject:(NSMutableArray*)prmotionDataArray;
```

In PromotionModel .m File Map Dictionary that pass form test method

```
 + (NSMutableArray*)getPromotionModelObject:(NSMutableArray*)prmotionDataArray{

NSMutableArray *prmotionDeatilArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
PromotionModel *promotionModel=nil;
for (NSMutableDictionary *promotinDetailDict in prmotionDataArray) {
    promotionModel=[[PromotionModel alloc]init];
    promotionModel.promotionid=[promotinDetailDict objectForKey:@"id"];

    promotionModel.promotionName=[promotinDetailDict objectForKey:@"name_en"];
    promotionModel.promotionDesc=[promotinDetailDict objectForKey:@"description_en"];


    promotionModel.promotionStartDate=[promotinDetailDict objectForKey:@"start_date"];
    promotionModel.promotionEndDate=[promotinDetailDict objectForKey:@"end_date"];
    [prmotionDeatilArray addObject:promotionModel];
}
    return prmotionDeatilArray;
}
```

Here model Class Completed

Now Here Sorting Logic With Related Methods

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortPromotionListWithEndDate:(NSMutableArray *)unsortedArray{
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0;i<[unsortedArray count];i++)
{
    PromotionModel *model =[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *dateStr=[self getDateinstaderdForm:model.promotionEndDate];
    NSDate *date=[self getDateFromString:dateStr];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:model forKey:@"entity"];
    [dict setObject:date forKey:@"date"];
    [tempArray addObject:dict];
}

NSInteger counter=[tempArray count];
NSDate *compareDate;
NSInteger index;
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
    index=i;
    compareDate=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDate *compareDateSecond;
    for(int j=i+1;j<counter;j++)
    {
        compareDateSecond=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSComparisonResult result = [compareDateSecond  compare:compareDate];
        if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            compareDate=compareDateSecond;
            index=j;
        }
    }
    if(i!=index)
        [tempArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:index];
}


[unsortedArray removeAllObjects];
for(int i=0;i<[tempArray count];i++)
{
    [unsortedArray addObject:[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"entity"]];
}
for (PromotionModel *model in unsortedArray) {
    NSLog(@" --------- New Object -------");
    NSLog(@"Promotion Name %@",model.promotionid);
    NSLog(@"Promotion Sort Details %@",model.promotionEndDate);
    NSLog(@"Promotion Name %@",model.promotionName);

}

return unsortedArray;

 }
```

Suported Method that use in logic For date formate.This is use to set All date in same format for match.

```
  - (NSString*)getDateinstaderdForm:(NSString*)currDate{
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *originalDate=[df dateFromString:currDate];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateStr=[df stringFromDate:originalDate];
return dateStr;
 }



 -(NSDate *) getDateFromString : (NSString *)stringDate
{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
//[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: stringDate];
return date;
 }
```

My Out Put

```
   --------- New Object -------
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.628 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name 2
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.639 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Sort Details 2014-01-25 00:00:00
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.643 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name Abcd
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.643 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b]  --------- New Object -------
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.644 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name 1
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.645 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Sort Details        2014-01-19 00:00:00
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.645 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name Abcd
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.646 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b]  --------- New Object -------
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.646 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name 2
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.658 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Sort Details 2013-12-01 00:00:00
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.661 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name Abcd
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.662 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b]  --------- New Object -------
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.663 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name 4
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.663 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Sort Details 2013-08-25 00:00:00
 2014-01-29 19:39:54.670 StackOverFlowSolutions[4756:a0b] Promotion Name Abcd
```

Try this this is working Hope This give you get desired OUTPUT

Comment: i have 8 key not only name and date its 8 and i have to sort this in NSUrlConnection method did Finish only.

Comment: @user2638242 You need to map your dictionary to model object edit code for that.

Comment: please tell me meaning of MAPromotionModel, MAObject? both are your controller iam calling method using   NSMutableArray *dataArray= [pramotion getPromotionModelObject:unfiltered]; here pramotion is my class

Comment: yes,PromotionModel is my NSObject type class it conent static (+)method GetPromotionModelObject Please check updated code

Comment: Dear i got result but not as in manner that i want its,
"2014-04-24","2013-09-20","2013-12-05","2013-09-18","2013-09-20","2013-09-27","2013-09-20","2013-09-18","2014-01-01","2013-12-10","2013-09-19","2013-11-18","2013-11-22","2013-11-18","2014-01-20","2014-02-04"

i am expecting like
2014-02-04","2014-04-24"2014-01-20
Upcoming date ascending order then Expire Date