# How to Sort NSMutableDictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to iOS development. I am creating NSMutableDictionary with Title, Count, Score. Now I want to sort my  NSMutableDictionary with the base of Count in Descending order. Please help me.

```
    self.top3_Question_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [item setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat: itemName] forKey:@"Title"];
    [item setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: itemCount] forKey:@"Count"];
    [item setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: itemScore] forKey:@"Score"];


    [self.top3_Question_Array addObject: item1];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary)

Comment: SHIDHIN please up vote and tick my answer if it is useful for you.Because others can get solution through your question also it can get more views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below coding.it works fine for me

```
NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[item setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: itemName] forKey:@"Title"];
[item setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: itemCount] forKey:@"Count"];
[item setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: itemScore] forKey:@"Score"];

[top3_Question_Array addObject:item];


NSSortDescriptor *countDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Count" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:countDescriptor, nil];
NSArray *sortedArrayOfDictionaries = [top3_Question_Array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
NSLog(@"sorted array of dictionaries: %@", sortedArrayOfDictionaries);
```

Also the expected output is

```
  sorted array of dictionaries: (
    {
    Count = 2;
    Score = 30;
    Title = Cholate;
 }
)
```

Comment: Thank, Its Works... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@"Title" : @"Hello", @"Count":@"3", @"Score":@"100"}, @{@"Title" : @"Hello", @"Count":@"2", @"Score":@"100"}, @{@"Title" : @"Hello", @"Count":@"1", @"Score":@"100"}, @{@"Title" : @"Hello", @"Count":@"4", @"Score":@"100"}];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Count"
                                                                 ascending:NO
                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sorted_array = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
    NSLog(@"sorted_array: %@", sorted_array);
```