# Sort mutable dictionary based on values of it

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have an unordered NSMutableDictioanry and this dictioanry is created as  in following example

```
{
    1 = 27;
    2 = 5;
    3 = 13964;
    4 = 2422;
    5 = 45;
    6 = 7;
    7 = 27;
    8 = 39;
}
```

i want to sort this dictionary based on values. And this can be done according to following article and it works perfectly fine   [Getting NSDictionary keys sorted by their respective values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708742/getting-nsdictionary-keys-sorted-by-their-respective-values) and will returns an array with keys sorted based on values

```
(
    2,
    6,
    7,
    1,
    8,
    5,
    4,
    3
)
```

So my question is there anyway that i can get a sorted dictionary directly instead of array

Comment: What do you want to do with the sorted dictionary?

Comment: NSDictionary don't care about sorting their keys, because it's a key access system and not an index access system to get the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Dictionary by values in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090016/sort-dictionary-by-values-in-swift)

Comment: the _dictionary_ is assorted like a _set_, you need to create an _array_ and put into that what you'd like to sort (e.g. keys).

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted collections by design. So, maybe not the right choice in your case...

Comment: i was trying to send the each dictionary values to table cell , so will need both key and value  (they will use in cell)

Comment: @Mr.G, then you could sort the keys e.g. into an _array_ based on the _value_ then restore back the _value_ from the _dictionary_ by the _array_'s  item (=_key_) for the actual index path.

Comment: yeah i was gonna do that , but i thought mutable dictionary would have a rich method to sort the dictioary

Comment: the _dictionary_'s keys are not sorted at all. what exactly would they be sorted by?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an NSMutableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a non-parallel object solution, you could use an array to store the key-value pairs as an array of two items. `keyValuePair[0]` is the key and `keyValuePair[1]` is the value.

```
- (NSArray *)sortedDataFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dictionary.count];

    for (NSNumber *key in [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
        NSArray *keyValuePair = @[key, dictionary[key]];
        [result addObject:keyValuePair];
    }

    return [result copy];
}
```

Early on, when the dictionary has been set (maybe in `-viewWillAppear:`).

```
self.sortedData = [self sortedDataFromDictionary:dictionary];
```

Then in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use

```
NSNumber *key = self.sortedData[indexPath.row][0];
NSNumber *value = self.sortedData[indexPath.row][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of parallel objects, but you might want to have a sorted array of keys and a dictionary.

Early on, when the dictionary has been set (maybe in `-viewWillAppear:`).

```
self.sortedKeys = [self.dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use

```
NSNumber *key = self.sortedKeys[indexPath.row];
NSNumber *value = self.dictionary[key];
```